# Unity3d :-Unity3d + Webgl+Lua build making error

Tags: unity-game-engine, lua

I am going to making the webgl demo game using unity3d game engine.
I am using lua script for the run my game. demo game is wokring standalone. 
but when i platform shift to the webgl. it is gettting errror.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a more detailed description of the error you are getting, and some relevant code samples. Without that it would be difficult for the community to diagnose your problem and provide good answers.

Comment: What's the Error ?

Answer (score 0):

When forwarding to an WebGL application everything from line endings of MAC,OSX must be universal because when compiled and formatted to run with WebPages the Application will tend to clue compiling errors and issues